# How to upload more than one file on the same page from different upload point. Using nodejs express-fileupload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have looked around on StackOverflow, but I can't see an answer applicable to me. I'm struggling since several hours to find a solution....

I have an handlebars page where the user can upload his files to the server and MySql database. For one file upload using `express` `file-upload` everything is working fine.
When I add the second upload point, and I leave empty the field on the front end with no file to upload on the terminal, and I submit the post request I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I understand that is expected since the field is empty and the object `name` remains empty as well, but, the user of my app must have the possibility to upload only one file with no error.

How can I go about this, to give the possibility to the user to upload only one file at a time with no error??

Any direction suggestion/solution to the right path is highly appreciated!! THANKS!

```html
 <input type="file" name="covid_19D" id="file_box" />
    <form class="row g-1 needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editcrew/{{this.id}}" encType="multipart/form-data"
      novalidate></form>



<input type="file" name="fitnesscert" id="file_box" />
    <form class="row g-1 needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editcrew/{{this.id}}" encType="multipart/form-data"
      novalidate></form>
```

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
message = '';
if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var post = req.body;
    var first_name = post.first_name;
    var last_name = post.last_name;
 

    if (req.files) {
        var file = req.files.covid_19D;
        var file2 = req.files.fitnessD;

        // console.log(profile_image)


        if (
            file && (file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
                file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
                file.mimetype == "image/gif" ||
                file.mimetype == "application/pdf")) {


            var covid_19D = file.name;
            file.mv('./upload/' + file.name, function (err) {

                if (err)

                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                else {


                    file2 && (file2.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
                        file2.mimetype == "image/png" ||
                        file2.mimetype == "image/gif" ||
                        file2.mimetype == "application/pdf")


                    var fitnessD = file2.name;
                    file2.mv('./upload/' + file2.name, function (err) {

                        if (err)

                            return res.status(500).send(err);


                        connection.query('UPDATE user SET first_name=? ,last_name=?, covid_19D=?,fitnessD=? WHERE id = ?', [first_name, last_name, covid_19D, fitnessD,  req.params.id], (err, rows) => {

                            if (!err) {
                                connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
                                    if (!err) {
                                        res.render('edit-crew', { rows, alert: `${first_name} has been updated.` });

                                    } else {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
                                });
                            } else {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
                        });

                    });
                };
            });
        }


    } else {
        connection.query('UPDATE user SET first_name=? ,last_name=? WHERE id = ?', [first_name, last_name, req.params.id], (err, rows) => {

            if (!err) {
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.render('edit-crew', { rows, alert: `${first_name} has been updated.` });

                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
            // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
        });





    }
}

}
```

For reference, I insert also the `app.js` file.

```js
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const busboy = require('then-busboy');
bodyParser=require("body-parser");

require("dotenv").config();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// Parsing middleware
const app = express();

// default option
app.use(fileUpload());

//to load static file
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("upload"));
//Listen on port 5000
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //To parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)

app.use(express.json()); //To parse the incoming requests with JSON bodies
app.use(cookieParser());

app.engine("hbs", exphbs({ extname: ".hbs" }));//Templating engine to change the extenion of file from .handlebar to .hbs
app.set("view engine", "hbs");



app.use("/", require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

and the `user.js` for the router:

```js
router.post('/editcrew/:id',userController.update);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your data is reaching the backend correctly. Also, I don't want to touch your code style.

If you just need to prevent your `file` and `file2` from throwing such type error`undefined`, do something like:

```
 if (req.files) {
  var file = req.files.covid_19D;

  if (
    file && (
        file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
        file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
        file.mimetype == "image/gif" ||
        file.mimetype == "application/pdf"
    )) {
       var covid_19D = file.name;
       // ...more code
  }
  // ...more code
 }
```

This way, `file.mimetype` and `file.name` is only being evaluated if `file == true`.
There is nothing wrong with `if..else`ing your way through, just make sure your objects have a value assigned. If it's undefined it means your user hasn't uploaded a file in the first place. Let it go.

Comment: Hi, I've applied your solution to the code. With one file is working fine. I edited the export.update above,  with the code as advised. I inserted `file2` with an else. When I'm trying to load  the page the following error appears. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` is referred to this line of code `  var fitnessD = file2.name;` . Any suggestions??

Comment: Try applying the same validation you did before to file2